# Scroll whole lines only Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

By default, in WPF you can scroll a textbox by part of a line. E.g. at the bottom of the textbox you can see the top half of the letters in the last line.

Is there any way of changing this functionality to work more like the textboxes in visual studio, which only scroll by whole lines?

Comment: Please add some code so that we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if this works on a TextBox, however you can try and use the [`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attached property.

Here is a simple example of how it can be used:

```
<TextBox Text="Some random text"
         ...
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="true"/>
```